# Spaces in references

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I have the following reference :

```
@misc{pcons,
author = {Energy.Gov},
title = {{Estimating Appliance and Home Electronic Energy Use}},
Howpublished = {\url{http://energy.gov/energysaver/articles/estimating-appliance-and-home-electronic-energy-use}},
note = {[April 26, 2013]},
year = {2012}
}
```

But it shows as :

[image]

I asked this before and was told to add `{\url` to fix the issue, however this time I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `\url` doesn't find an appropriate breaking point in the given URL; you can help it, by adding a new possible breaking point to `\UrlBreaks` (the default list for possible breaks):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abcd.bib}
@misc{pcons,
author = {Energy.Gov},
title = {{Estimating Appliance and Home Electronic Energy Use}},
Howpublished = {\url{http://energy.gov/energysaver/articles/estimating-appliance-and-home-electronic-energy-use}},
note = {[April 26, 2013]},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\-}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{pcons}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{abcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example I chose `-` as a new possible break point, but this perhaps is not the better choice? Select whichever character suits you best.

For the record, here's the default list of possible break points:

```
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
 \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
```